# Find the value of $3qx^2-2px+3q$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $\frac{\sqrt{p+3q}+\sqrt{p-3q}}{\sqrt{p+3q}-\sqrt{p-3q}}=x$ then,find the value of $3qx^2-2px+3q$.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: If you're completely stuck, try rationalize the denominator first.

Comment: And think about the roots of $3qx^2-3px+3q$.

Comment: I have already rationalized the denominator to get the result $3qx=p+\sqrt{p^2-9q^2}$.I am stuck over here.

Comment: try removing the square root

Comment: @user291957 How to do so?

Comment: take your time and give it a try

Comment: @user291957 Still not able to get it .Please help.

Comment: just subtract p on both sides and then again square on both sides and then simplify

Comment: @user291957 Thanks a lot for your help.Tomorrow I have my exams thus your solution is very helpgul for me.

Comment: @user291957 please write up your solution as an answer and i will definitely accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from where you were stuck

$3qx=p+\sqrt{p^2-9q^2}$

subtracting p on both sides and then squaring we get

$(3qx-p)^2 = p^2-9q^2$

$\implies 9q^2x^2+p^2-6pqx=p^2-9q^2$

subtracting $p^2$ on both sides and then taking 3q common on both sides
$3q(3qx^2-2px+3q)=0$

$\implies 3qx^2-2px+3q=0$

Comment: Sorry for the delay.Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sqrt{p+3q}+\sqrt{p-3q}}{\sqrt{p+3q}-\sqrt{p-3q}}=x \stackrel{\color{red}{C\&D}}{\implies}   \frac{2\sqrt{p+3q}}{2\sqrt{p-3q}}=\dfrac{x+1}{x-1}$$

Square both sides and it becomes clear what needs to be done next

Refer [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo) for componendo and dividendo rule